# Doctrine2 query something as: select * from table where column like '1%'

Tags: symfony

Can someone help me in creating query in Doctrine:
I'm using:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('CompanyStoreBundle:Employee');


$employees = $repository->findBy(
    array (), 
    array('nomenklBr' => 'ASC')
    );
```

...and it is working, but I want add filter so relsult contains only records with values of nomenkl-column which starts with "1".
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dql for this as given below :

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dql = 'SELECT e FROM CompanyStoreBundle:Employee e ORDER BY e.id ASC WHERE e.nomenklBr like "1.%" ';
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $employees = $query->getResult();
```